# What was the entropy of the universe during inflation?

Tags: entropy, cosmological-inflation

What was the entropy of the universe a) during inflation; b) at the end of inflation (at reheating, begin of the big bang)?

Comment: Is it okay to regard entropy density in an answer or do you want it strictly limited to entropy?

Comment: The amount of entropy would be interesting in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

$S = 10^{15}$$k_B$ is the approximate figure for a volume equivalent to the Observable Universe during Inflation, arrived at by calculating the Unruh Radiation generated by the presence of a cosmological horizon. This is the period before the Hot Big Bang (from $10^{-36}$ seconds until $10^{-33}$ seconds). This figure doesn't change much during that time.

After Inflation, when the field energy was converted into particles, the entropy rose significantly: $S = 10^{88}$$k_B$ is the approximate figure. Once matter began to dominate, the rate of increase slowed to bring an additional 15 orders of magnitude in all the time since. That's an curious symmetry with the inflationary period (for us alive now) but entropy is predicted to reach a maximum of $S=10^{120}$$k_B$ once black holes evaporate.